# jquery - minimum number of words in textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I've been looking everywhere for a function that would control the minimum number of words entered in the textarea and, in a case the user doesn't put the minimum number of words (250 let's say), an alert would appear once he tries to submit the message.

I am using this theme: http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=AskIt

This is how the form is submitted:

```
<form action="<?php echo(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>#create_new_post" method="post">
```

And this is the textarea code:

```
<textarea name="et_newpost_content" id="et_newpost_content" class="input"><?php if ( isset( $_POST['et_newpost_content'] ) ) echo esc_textarea( $_POST['et_newpost_content'] ); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: How about use `$('textarea').val()` and check it's `lenght` ?

Comment: Here's a relatively old but well written ( and recently updated ) plugin that does this: http://keith-wood.name/maxlength.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your form tag so it reads:

```
<form onsubmit="checktextarea()" action="<?php echo(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>#create_new_post" method="post">
```

then in your javascript, enter

```
function checktextarea() {

   var minLength = 15;

   var $textarea = $('#et_newpost_content');
   if($textarea.text().length < minLength) {
      alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength ' + characters');
      return false;
   }
}
```

This will prevent the form from being submitted unless the character length of the text in the text area is greater than whatever you set for minLength.

**EDIT**

I see I misread the question and counted characters and not words.  If you need words (and props to @João) the function should read something like

```
function checktextarea() {

   var minLength = 15;

   var $textarea = $('#et_newpost_content');
   if($textarea.text().split(/\s+/).length < minLength) {
      alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength + ' words');
      return false;
   }
}
```

The [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function uses a regular expression to split the text in the textarea by whitespace characters and puts that into an array.  Then you check the array's length to see if you have enough words

**EDIT 2**

In a Wordpress site running in [noConflict](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers) mode, the snippet should look like

```
function checktextarea() {

   var minLength = 15;

   var $textarea = jQuery('#et_newpost_content');
   if($textarea.text().split(/\s+/).length < minLength) {
      alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength + ' words');
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the form will be submitted whichever function is there. It is like the ajax that submits the form overrides all the other functions. Any ideas? This is where everything happens: [link]http://www.wherescientistsdream.com/?page_id=5

Comment: from looking at the page itself, wordpress is running in jQuery noConflict mode, so the snippet I provided is throwing an error instead of returning false, so the form goes ahead and submits. I should have accounted for that; my apologies. See edit.

Comment: It works better now (the function activates), but with errors. If you test it on my site, you will notice that the message shows regardless of the number of words put there (if easier, we could put limit in characters, at least 1000), while the form is submitted anyway, right after I click ok on the alert box (regardless on the number of words).

Comment: My mistake (and sorry for the delay).  instead of checking the text(), try checking the val(), so: `$textarea.val().split(/\s+/).length`. If that works properly I'll update my answer.

Comment: The function works properly now (it alerts fine if there is less than 15 words there, but even if there isn't 15 words, it still submits the form after I click "Ok" on the alert box. Is there a way to force the form to stop here?

Comment: Perhaps this will help, this is the code for the submit button: `<input type="hidden" name="et_add_answer" value="proccess" />
           <input class="register" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Submit','AskIt'); ?>" id="submit" />`

Comment: If I remove this part '<input type="hidden" name="et_add_answer" value="proccess" />', the form will not submit.

Comment: It gave me an extra count when there was white spaces at the end. So I had to trim: $.trim(textarea.val()).split(/\s+/).length

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean words or characters? If you want to count **words**, a very naïve approach is splitting by whitespace and check the length of the resulting array:

```
if ($("#et_newpost_content").text().split(/\s+/).length < 250) {
  alert('Message must be at least 250 words.')
}
```

If you mean **characters**, then it's much easier:

```
if ($("#et_newpost_content").text().length < 250) {
  alert('Message must be at least 250 characters.')
}
```

Comment: I think it's characters but can't really say that definitively.